# How to do asp.net webapi routing when it comes to custom models?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I am developing an ASP.Net WebApi application and facing some difficulties with routing. I have following code in my WebApi controller.

```
public class UserRegistrationServiceWebApiController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void RegisterUser(RegisterUser registerUser)
    {
        /*Some code here*/

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ConfirmUserPassword(UserPasswordConfirmModel userPasswordData)
    {
        /*Some code here*/
    }
}
```

In my RouteConfig.cs, I have given the routes like this.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UserRegistrationApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{firstName}/{lastName}/{email}/{phoneNo}/{company}"
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UserPasswordConfirmationApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{password}"
        );
```

The attributes here (firstName, lastName etc) are getting filled properly from the client-side and I can see them in server-side when I call these two actions separately. But when both actions are in the controller, it says it cannot identify which action to pick. This is obviously because of the custom objects i am filling in the server-side (RegisterUser model and UserPasswordConfirmModel model). So there is a conflict there.

This is because of the routing problem. Appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Actually I found out the problem is with the conflict of two actions in the same controller. If I use these two actions separately they work fine. I do not know how to handle when we have two actions in the same controller like above.
I looked in to custom parameter binding, but I do not think that is the problem since my actions work fine separately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer, do not have two actions on the same controller. But if you want to, use specific routes (add a constraint). Also, is there a reason to have the password in the url?

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "UserRegistrationApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{firstName}/{lastName}/{email}/{phoneNo}/{company}",
        constraints = new { action = "RegisterUser" }
    );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "UserPasswordConfirmationApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{password}",
       constraints = new { action = "ConfirmUserPassword" }
    );
```

Comment: "What" did not work? Exceptions? Errormessage? Does it always go to the same route no matter what you do?

Comment: yes sir, it says the same error message as there are one or more actions in the controller which can match this route..